# Handle DOM events in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, events

I am new to Angular and trying to understand what is the best approach to handle DOM events in Angular similar to what we use to do in jQuery. For example, in the HTML code below, I would like to add a new CSS class named `open` to all sections with class `filter-section` when `btnfilter` button is clicked -

```html
<aside class="filter ng-scope" id="search-filters">
                    <button class="btn btn-filter in" id="btnfilter">
                        <i class="ico ico-collapsed"></i>
                        <i class="ico ico-expand none"></i>
                    </button>
                    <section class="refine filter-section">
                        <span class="sub-title" title="Filter">
                            <i class="ico ico-gr-filter"></i>
                            <span class="title none">FILTERS</span>
                        </span>
                    </section>
<section class="refine filter-section">
                        <span class="sub-title" title="Filter">
                            <i class="ico ico-gr-filter"></i>
                            <span class="title none">FILTERS</span>
                        </span>
                    </section>
 </aside>
```

In jQuery, we could have done something like below -

```
  $('#btnfilter').click(function () {
      $(this).find('.filter-section').addClass('new-class');
  });
```

I would like to know the Angular way of achieving the same. Please advise.

Comment: You can use 'click' event of Angular <section class="refine filter-section" (click)="myClickFunction()"></section>

Comment: @Alex, How do I reference all DOM elements with class 'filter-section' in my .ts file?

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean or anything, but this is basic Angular. There are MILLIONS of results on the internet for this. All you had to do was search... The amount of time you put into making this post and waiting for an answer, you could've found your answer on Google.

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 I am pretty sure this is basics but my bad, unable to find something that suits my need, hence this question. Hoping for a link or an answer here.

Comment: For example: In the function you have bound to a click event, you can use plain JS to search through the DOM and look for said class. If it has it add the new class. Whether that be with JS or inside of [ngClass] or something. (That is just a rough example)

Comment: I would disagree that this is "basic Angular". I don't believe there is anything in the docs that discusses this. And after some googling myself I'm not finding any good "Angular" answer to this. Mostly just how to use jQuery from Angular. (Which most devs consider to be less than best practices.)

Comment: Thanks @DeborahK for understanding.

Comment: @All, who are downvoting the question, please add a comment for the downvote.

Comment: I think the question is clear ... and is actually a great question because the answer is not obvious. i don't know why it is being voted down or put on hold??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the usual Angular Property Binding to add your class and provide a ***flag*** variable in you Typescript file like this.

```
export class YourComponent {

  isBtnToggled: boolean = false;

  constructor() {}

  toggleClass() {
    this.isBtnToggled = !this.isBtnToggled;
  }
}
```

Your Html template should look like that:

```
<aside class="filter ng-scope" id="search-filters">
    <button class="btn btn-filter in" id="btnfilter" (click)="toggleClass()">
        <i class="ico ico-collapsed"></i>
        <i class="ico ico-expand none"></i>
    </button>
    <section class="refine filter-section" [class.css-class-here]="isBtnToggled">
        <span class="sub-title" title="Filter">
            <i class="ico ico-gr-filter"></i>
            <span class="title none">FILTERS</span>
        </span>
    </section>
</aside>
```

So what we did here is, we created a function **toggleClass()** in your Typescript File that toggles the value of your Variable **isBtnToggled**. When you click the button your value will change thus, **Angular Property Binding [class.your-css-class]** will trigger and add your CSS Class on your element. If you have multiple **filter-section** classes, you can follow the same binding and it will work just the same for the rest of them.

You could also use plain JavaScript and just use the `querySelectorAll('.filter-section')` example that DeborahK provided, but i suggest that you stay away from DOM manipulation in angular. Its slow, heavy, and will not work 100% with other techniques like Angular Universal (Server Side Rendering) etc.

I hope i helped you, Cheers

Comment: your solution works great!

Comment: I am glad i helped you. Don't forget to set the topic as answered! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with:

```
  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let elementList = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.filter-section');
    elementList.forEach(element => {
      // element.className += ' new-class';
      element.classList.add('new-class');
      console.log(element);
    });
  }
```

This finds all of the elements with the defined query selector and for each one, adds the requested class.

Comment: How good it is to use plain jQuery DOM manipulation in Angular codes? I agree that this works but as @John mentioned in his post, it's slow & heavy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on this using Renderer2. This should be server side rendering (SSR) safe, and avoid any coupling to the DOM.

First, I added a template varaible (`#filterSection`) to the `section` below.

```
<aside class="filter ng-scope" id="search-filters">
<button class="btn btn-filter in" id="btnfilter" (click)="getFunky()">
    <i class="ico ico-collapsed"></i>
    <i class="ico ico-expand none"></i>
</button>
<section class="refine filter-section" #filterSection>
    <span class="sub-title" title="Filter">
        <i class="ico ico-gr-filter"></i>
        <span class="title none">FILTERS</span>
    </span>
</section>
</aside>
```

And this is the component code that I put together:

```
import { Component, Renderer2, AfterViewInit,
    ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-filter-section',
    templateUrl: './filter-section.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./filter-section.component.css']
})
export class FilterSectionComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('filterSection') filterSection: ElementRef;
    private filterElement: HTMLElement;

    constructor(private renTwo: Renderer2) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        if (this.filterSection && this.filterSection.nativeElement) {
            this.filterElement = this.filterSection.nativeElement;
        }
    }

    getFunky() {
      this.renTwo.addClass(this.filterElement, 'new-class');
    }
}
```

This gets Renderer2 via constructor injection. In the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle method, I check the `filterSection` ElementRef to make sure it is truthy, and has a `nativeElement`. If so, assign the `nativeElement` to a local private variable for use within the component. In the click function (`getFunky`), using Renderer2, I add a class with the `addClass` function, passing in the private `filterElement` and the class I want to add.

Renderer2 can be used to do a wide variety of DOM manipulation. See below.

[Renderer2 reference](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)

Comment: Just note that Renderer2 will (soon?) be replaced with Ivy: https://github.com/robwormald/ivy-code-size

Comment: @DeborahK, is that the code name for Renderer3? Sort of seems like it. They have to get away from throwing numbers behind the name. :) Thanks for the information!!

Comment: As I am starting on Angular, I would avoid using Renderer2. May be when ngIvy is out, I can implement that :)

Comment: @R.Richards Here is the link for Ivy: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21706

Comment: @DeborahK, fantastic stuff! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers quite get the angular way of doing things.

You're stated goal is to have all elements with a certain class on a page add class when a button is clicked.

I want to generalize this a bit and say, you want all elements of a certain type to react in a certain way to an event.

step 1 is the binding which you seem familiar with:

```
<button (click)="broadcastEvent()">My Event Button</button>
```

This is simple click event binding that everyone who's read an angular tutorial should know.

Next we need to have some way of broadcasting and receiving the event, this is a case for an angular service:

```
@Injectable()
export class EventBroadcastService {
    private eventSource = new Subject();
    event$ = this.eventSource.asObservable();
    broadcastEvent() {
        this.eventSource.next();
    }
}
```

this is a simple service that has an rxjs subject and observable. The service exposes an API that allows consumers to send events and listen to them.  back to our original component that contains our button, we'll inject the service and tie our button click to this function:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'event-button',
  template: `<button (click)="broadcastEvent()">My Event Button</button>`
})
export class EventButtonComponent {
    constructor(private eventBroadcastService: EventBroadcastService) {}

    broadcastEvent() {
      this.eventBroadcastService.broadcastEvent();
    }
}
```

now, finally we need to define a consumer of this event to react to it:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[eventConsumer]'
})
export class EventConsumerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(private eventBroadcastService: EventBroadcastService) {}
    @HostBinding(‘class’) addClass = '';
    private eventSub;
    ngOnInit() {
       this.eventSub = this.eventBroadcastService.event$.subscribe(e => this.addClass = 'new-class');
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
      this.eventSub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

this directive can be applied to any arbitrary element and allow you to manipulate the class.

Finally we put it together:

```
@Component({
   template: `
       <event-button></event-button>
       <section class="filter-section" eventConsumer>
          CONTENT
       </section>
    `,
    providers: [EventBroadcastService]
})
export class MainComponent {

}
```

This example is fairly contrived, but hopefully gets the point across of how you can use a mix of components, directives and services to achieve similar results to jquery in a more controlled manner.  This might seem like a lot for something simple but puttnig in infrastrucutre like this yields dividends in large complex applications.

However, this is still pretty cumbersome for something that seems fairly simple.  The reason it seems this way is because you're still in the jQuery mindset and need to migrate your thinking and approach to the angular style. You want to use the class directive like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-filter in" id="btnfilter" (click)="applyClass = true">
    <i class="ico ico-collapsed"></i>
    <i class="ico ico-expand none"></i>
</button>
<section class="refine filter-section" [class.new-class]="applyClass">
```